# How to freeze label in TextField?

Tags: flutter

I have label in the top left corner of my TextField. I want the user to be able to see the hint always (and after that he filled the form), but it disappears when I tap.

[image: My code]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
            label: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  _text,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                )),
            focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
            enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            )));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [material design suggest](https://m3.material.io/components/text-fields/overview) to use the `labelText` property on the `InputDecoration`. Maybe you have already tried and dismissed it.. but I'm checking just in case... have you tried that?

This will be the typical outcome:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I want fix label in the corner without breaking a border

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to go with hintText, you can make a stack where the first child is the ’TextField’ and the other is [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) for your text.

Comment: Sounds good! I thought about that, but I am not sure it going to work correctly on different screen sizes